# typeof (Array, null) returns object and typeof(null, Array) returns function

Tags: javascript

As the title says it all, `typeof (Array, null)` returns `object` and `typeof(null, Array)` returns `function`.

It returns the type of the second parameter.

Why ?

Comment: An interview question? Hope not a job  interview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

- `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so `typeof(expr)` is `typeof expr`, with `expr` [evaluated first](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)
- [`a,b` returns `b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

So

`typeof (a, b)` returns `typeof b`

and in your case

- `typeof (Array, null)` is `typeof null` [which is `"object"`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)
- `typeof(null, Array)` is `typeof Array`, and `Array` is a function.

Comment: Why `(a,b)` returns b?

Comment: @2619 [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)