# Javascript - brackets in console.log method issue

Tags: javascript

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557263/typeof-array-null-returns-object-and-typeofnull-array-returns-function) inspired me. I've made some tests.

`console.log( false, 5 );` prints `false 5` , and it's ok.

`console.log(  ( false, 5 )  );` prints `5`. Now we know that it's ok too because `( false, 5 )` returns `5`.

But why does `console.log(  false, {}, 5  );` print `false Object {} 5`?

Also `console.log( ( false, {}, 5 ) );` and even `console.log( ( false, { i:0 }, 5 ) );` both prints `5`. Why is `5` is preferred to `{}`?

You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/3uUwY/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) always returns the last element, which is 5.

Comment: oh , i thought it returns first one that is not undefined or null

Comment: That would have been a || b || c.

Answer (score 1):

When using brackets you are forcing Javascript to evaluate that expression.

```
console.log(a, b, c); // 3 parameters, the function prints a, b and c

console.log((a, b, c)); // 1 parameter. It prints the result of 
                        // evaluating (a, b, c) and, as it's said 
                        // in the other answer, it returns the last element
                        // of the expression.
```

Comment: Thank you , now i know that it is always last element

Answer (score 1):

By putting brakets you make only one argument to console.log. So following

```
console.log( false, 5 ); // here you are using log function with 2 argumetns
```

And here

```
console.log( ( false, { i:0 }, 5 ) ); // here is only one argument.
```

Inside a brakets you are using comma operator.

And the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) always returns last expression.

So you could rewrite your expression like this:

```
var x = ( false, { i:0 }, 5 ); // x is 5 here
console.log( x );
```

Comment: Declaring multiple variables by separating them with a comma is unrelated to the comma operator.

Comment: @Juhana And what operator is using there?

Comment: It's not an operator, it's just part of the variable-declaring syntax.

Comment: When used to separate elements like when declaring variables or separating arguments in a function, it's not an operator. It's only an operator when it's used as such. (If you don't believe me, look up what the [definition of an operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(programming)) is.)

Comment: @hazzik The example at the bottom of the page you linked to says the comma used when declaring multiple variables is not an operator. But something like `i++, j--` is.

Answer (score 1):

By putting brakets you make only one argument to console.log. So following

```
console.log( false, 5 ); // here you are using log function with 2 argumetns
```

And here

```
console.log( ( false, { i:0 }, 5 ) ); // here is only one argument.
```

Inside a brakets you are using comma operator.

And the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) always returns last expression.

So you could rewrite your expression like this:

```
var x = ( false, { i:0 }, 5 ); // x is 5 here
console.log( x );
```